# Coordinate system problem with the grid control

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application im trying to visualize some temperature data. I have a list of temperatures for the 7 past days and want to make a point to point line diagram. My problem is with the different koordinatesystems and adjusting data to the grid.

XAML:

```
<Grid Height="167" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="455" />
```

C# (draft):

http://pastebin.com/6UWkMFj1

scale is a global variable that changes with a slider (1-10). How to i correct my application so the line always is centered? As it is now it starts out centeded but if i crank up the slider to 3-4 the line goes up and above the applicationwindow. I also would like to use the full height of the grid window not just a small piece like images below:

http://img32.imageshack.us/i/002wtvu.jpg/
http://img691.imageshack.us/i/001tqco.jpg/

As you can see i have worked out my data so day 1 with temperature 62 F is lower then day 2 with temperature of 76 F but i have scaling issues and placementissues... could somebody straighten out my math? :-)

Comment: Can you post the full XAML of the UserControl or Window?  It'd help to see how everything is oriented in the context of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that drawing on a grid is a good idea... Canvas should do... give it a try. Here is a [link with related stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) that might be helpful.

Comment: There I go. Im very new to WPF so I just thought I could draw on the first and best thing I found in the toolbox at a glance :D